# My Toshiba R830 wont play any sound, do I need drivers or else?

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I just installed Ubuntu on my R830 but for some odd reason I dont hear any kind of sound. I dont know if it's driver based or if my speakers or even Soundcard just died on me for some weird reason. Anyways I'm hoping for some help! (I'm new to Ubuntu so you'll have to explain every detail to me, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you should install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package

At first you should update the repositories with this:

```
    sudo apt-get update
```

and then:

```
    sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```